# apply field reshape to all documents in a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have had the following User schema with already a good amount of users saved in the db:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  country: String,
  authorities: [{ code: String, description: String }]
  ...
});
```

I have decided to save authorities by country, so the schema becomes :

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  country: String,
  authorities: [{
    country: String,
    authorities: [{ code: String, description: String }]
  }]
  ...
});
```

My question is, how do I update already saved users to reflect schema update?
NB: there is only one country right now.

Comment: Have you looked at using a [pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/index.html#update-command-u) with update?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find the right operators to get the job done

Comment: You'll probably just need to use `$addFields` or `$set`

Comment: Well for $addFields, I dont think it is the case because we are not adding new fields. We are just reshaping the same field, and for $set, if we do it we risk to lose our authorities.